# nsubstitute giving exception while creating substitute

Tags: c#, .net, nsubstitute, glass-mapper

We are Trying to integrate Nunit testing within our web application. here we are using Nsubstitute as a mocking framework.
The project architecture goes as below:

```
Public class BaseService : Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreContext
{
    public BaseService(){}
}

Public class DerivedService : BaseService
{
    IGenericRepository<Item> _genericRepository;

    public DerivedService ( IGenericRepository<Item> _repository)
    {
        _genericRepository= _repository;
    }

    public string DoSomethig(){}
}
```

Now to test the DoSomething() method of my DerivedService class i am creating the substitue of my repository and faking its response. which should let me test my service code.

```
[Test]
public void TestDoSomethigMethod()
{
    var repository = Substitute.For<IGenericRepository<Item>>();

    DerivedService tempService = new DerivedService(repository);
    // Throws an exception of type System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary. at base service constructor.
    var response = tempService.DoSomething();
}
```

When i try to invoke the instance of derived service it throws me the exception at baseService constructor saying (The given key was not present in the dictionary)
we are using windsor castle for dependency injection & the Base Class inherits from Glass Mapper sitecore context class.
Please let me know if anyone faced any such problem or have a solution for this.

edit: code for test case updated as suggested by Pavel & Marcio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSubstitute` will *proxy* `public` and `virtual` methods/properties only. You should either substitute interfaces or make sure the classes you substitute expose `public virtual` methods. As far as I can tell, yours are not `virtual` and while `NSubstitute` can create the object, it can't effectively proxy/mock anything on it.

Also, if your constructor is not parameter-less make sure you are providing a substitute (or a real instance) for every argument when *substituting*.

More details here: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a substitute for `DerivedService`, but for `IGenericRepository<Item>` and inject it into `DerivedService`.

You'll only create substitutes for the parts you want to mock, not the ones you want to test.

Here's what you should do:

```
[Test]
public void TestDoSomethigMethod()
{
    var repository = Substitute.For<IGenericRepository<Item>>();
    // Here you set up repository expectations
    DerivedService tempService = new DerivedService(repository);

    var response = tempService.DoSomething();

    // Here you assert the response
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but while doing that i am getting the same exception while creating the instance of derived service.
DerivedService tempService = new DerivedService(repository);

Comment: Are the constructors for DerivedService and BaseService exactly the same as you've provided as example?